# Does Edge Ngram Token filter creates Synonym for tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, tokenize

I have added Edge Ngram Token Filter to my analyzer, **ngram_back_fa**.
Here is my analyzer:

```
"ngram_back_fa": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "decimal_digit",
                        "trim",
                        "reverse",
                        "edge_ngram_filter",
                        "reverse"
                    ]
                }
```

Here is my filed, **title_en**:

```
"title_en": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "title_en_analyzer",
                "boost": 40,
                "fields": {
                    "with_back_ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_back_en",
                        "boost": ngram_boost
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my search query is like this:

```
{
     "query": {
            "dis_max": {
                "queries": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "HomeComing",
                            "type": "best_fields",
                                "title_en.with_back_ngram"
                                ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    
}
```

When I use Explain API to see how this analyzer is calculating my score I see that apparently, the tokens that are generated by **token filter** are like **Synonym** of the original tokens and therefore the score are really low. You can see the result of Explain API in the below image:

[Explain API Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrnKd.png)

How Can I make elastic to stop this and treat this tokens (generated by **token filter**) the sane way it treats with the token generated by **tokenizer**?